# Symfony2 - is there a way to test custom events/event listeners?

Tags: php, symfony

My question title is essentially my entire problem - I have an event listener I need to unit/functional test outside the context of a controller, and I'm unsure how to do it.  Any tutorials/guides available on this?

Comment: Can we at least see your code, or more about the problem? What event are you intercepting?

Comment: Test as in see it work or unit test?

Comment: Unit/functional test, outside of the context of a controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing an event listener is very easy: simply call the listener method and verify that the expected actions are executed.

Comment: How can I invoke the listener in a unit/functional test scenario?  Is it possible to simply grab the dispatcher in that context?

Comment: @MajorProductions You should call the listener method as a normal class and method with a prepared event instance according to what you're testing. No need to use the dispatcher when only testing the listener. The listener doesn't know about the dispatcher and it shouldn't know.